# Upsert with $in

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I want following functionality in MongoDB. I have a collection named 'entities', which basically stores entity text and it's count. The collection looks like this:

```
[{u'_id': u'facebook', u'n': 120},
 {u'_id': u'florida', u'n': 98},
 {u'_id': u'vegas', u'n': 94},
 {u'_id': u'andrew_mason', u'n': 93},
 {u'_id': u'obama', u'n': 85},
 {u'_id': u'twitter', u'n': 81},
 {u'_id': u'outlook', u'n': 81},
 {u'_id': u'delhi', u'n': 75},
 {u'_id': u'google', u'n': 74},
 {u'_id': u'virginia', u'n': 71}]
```

Now, I want to update this collection with new Entities. Basically, I'll have new entities ready in an Array like this:

```
entitySet = ['google', 'Abhishek_Vaid', 'andrew_mason']
```

My intentions are that, for the entities already in the collection their count should be updated. As for entities **not** in the collection, their count should be initialized to 1. I want to use a single MongoDB query to achieve both these effects. Till now I've been able to find following query : (**It's in PyMongo flavor, but it's nonetheless a MongoDB query**)

ENTITY_DB_HANDLE.entities.update (

```
{'_id' : {'$in' : entitySet} }, {'$inc' : {'n' : 1} }, upsert=True, multi=True )
```

However, this query only updates the existing entity counts and does not push new entities.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly does work :

```
> db.test.save({_id:"a", n:3})
> db.test.update({_id:"b"}, {$inc:{n:1}}, true, false)
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : "a", "n" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "b", "n" : 1 }
```

But your example query doesn't use $in so I'm assuming you're actually trying :

```
{'_id' : {$in:['google', 'Abhishek_Vaid', 'andrew_mason']}, {'$inc' : {'n' : 1} }, upsert=True, multi=True )
```

and expect it to update or create an entry for each _id value you pass. This will not work if any of the _id values already exists since upsert will only create a new document of no document matches the search criteria.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I've updated the question. Kindly once again have a look. But I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek Already did in the second half of my answer ;) That will not ever work because that's not how upsert works. To do what you want to do you will have to iterate over the unique id's and invoke an upsert=true update for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Ya, I was hoping to kind of avoid it. However, I'm still not convinced why it is not working. Because, upsert=True, clearly means that for every document processed, (through _id match), if the document is non-existent, my intentions are to insert it. I mean, if it is not gonna work, then I might as well don't provide upsert option and only deal with multi=True. Then what is the use of upsert option in the first place?

Comment: Not sure what behavior you expect here, could you clarify what exactly you would like it to do?  As Remon mentioned the update will insert a new document if it does not find a match for the query.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek The usecase for upsert is as follows : It will create a new document if, and only if, NONE of the documents in the collection match your search criteria. Your $in based query does match one or more documents and therefore will not result in a new document. Basically you can think of it like this; upsert will only ever create at most one document. For your line of reasoning it could potentially create up to X documents where X is the number of ID values in your $in.

Comment: I was hoping for something that could insert X missing documents in a single call - rather than having to make a roundtrip for each item in the array - maybe in some future version...

Comment: Afraid not, and note that's actually a very tricky feature to implement.