# How to upsert multiple records based on $in operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Given a collection `example`:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59635df23f0ee432913d908b"),
  "a" : "TRK-001",
  "b" : "ca21d580-801c-4e4c-8f16-7b5b8959924a",
  "c" : "PENDING",
  "d" : ISODate("2017-07-10T10:58:58.213Z")
}
```

I want to update multiple records where `a` match with a provided array of values,
set the value of `b` to a different value. If there is no `a` that matches
with the provided values, I want to insert one record per each value in the array.

An approach that makes sense to me is to execute an `update` with both `multi` and
`upsert` set to `true`.

```
db.example.update({
  "a": { $in: [ "TRK-001", "TRK-002", "TRK-003" ] },
  "c": "PENDING"
}, {
  $set: { b: "2b46d749-37e9-472a-8cd9-11535f31dd90" },
  $setOnInsert: { d: new Date() }
}, {
  "multi" : true, "upsert" : true
});
```

But the result is not what I'm expecting:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5963608f3f0ee432913d908f"),
  "c" : "PENDING",
  "b" : "2b46d749-37e9-472a-8cd9-11535f31dd90",
  "d" : ISODate("2017-07-10T11:10:07.057Z")
}
```

Only one record is created and no reference to value `a`.

Is there a way to do this either with plain mongodb and spring-data-mongodb?

Comment: this might help, This answer is not selected but reading the comments might help u understand the functionality of upsert true

Comment: @PiyushKumar did you missed any copy and paste? :)

Comment: It's probably something wrong with your query, I would make sure, that the query is matches the expectaion.

Comment: @Pedro Tavares Sorry my mistake , this was the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198336/upsert-with-in

Comment: Mongo does not allow this kind of query. The upsert flag can create, at most, only one record. I'll have to do it step by step.